# supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange not firing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am implementing a toast action after the user logged in or out with `supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange()`. But it does not seem to work properly as it.

My app is running on NextJs 13 and React 18 with the old `page` structure.

**_app.tsx**

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  let [supabase] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') console.log('signed in')
      if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') console.log('signed out')
    })
  })

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
        <div className="fixed inset-0 flex justify-center sm:px-8">
          <div className="flex w-full max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
            <div className="w-full bg-white ring-1 ring-gray-100 dark:bg-zinc-900 dark:ring-zinc-300/20" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="relative">
          <Header />
          <main>
            <Component previousPathname={previousPathname} {...pageProps} />
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
        <Analytics />
        <Toaster />
    </SessionContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: We need more information to understand what is going on. What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior? Do you see any error logs in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution were i missed out the dep

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  let [supabase] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') console.log('signed in')
      if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') console.log('signed out')
    })
  }, [supabase])

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
        <div className="fixed inset-0 flex justify-center sm:px-8">
          <div className="flex w-full max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
            <div className="w-full bg-white ring-1 ring-gray-100 dark:bg-zinc-900 dark:ring-zinc-300/20" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="relative">
          <Header />
          <main>
            <Component previousPathname={previousPathname} {...pageProps} />
          </main>
          <Footer />
        </div>
        <Analytics />
        <Toaster />
    </SessionContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: To clarify: The only difference is adding `[supabase]` as a second argument to `useEffect()`.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is stuck like me, I had this same issue and for me the problem was that supabase's signUp method doesn't trigged the onAuthStateChange event. Only methods like signInWithPassword or SignOut do.